# iptables log file

Tags: logs, iptables

I have ubuntu and I want to know where can I find the log file of iptables?
I find out `/var/log/messages`, but I am not sure this is a correct log file or not.

And I also want to know when this log file is changed? I add one rule to prevent my machine to respond to ping message but when I ping my machine I didn't see any changes to `/var/log/messages`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it can easily fill up your logs, the default is to not log. Add a jump to the LOG target, which will log to the kernel log (which you can see with `dmesg` or at wherever syslog is configured to write that for your distro). In your LOG-target rule, you can set `--log-level` and `--log-prefix` to help organize the messages and keep them separate from other kernel messages.

LOG is a "non-terminating target", so rule traversal will continue on to the next rule — you can basically add logging right above your existing rules without affecting them.

Answer (score 7):

IPTables doesn't log unless you add a rule to add a log entry.  This is typically done with the -j LOG destination.  The log entry is sent to the kernel log, and your syslog daemon determines where kernel log entries go, which seems to be /var/log/messages in your case.

If you want to block pings from a certain host (a fictional 123.456.789.10 for example), and log all those packets, run:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 --source 123.456.789.10 -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 --source 123.456.789.10 -j DROP
```

Comment: Do note, however, that logging every single packet marked for dropping is liable to fill up your log filesystem really, really fast...

Comment: Agreed, that's why I only logged for a particular source IP.

Comment: Adding `-m limit --limit 4/min --limit-burst 10` also helps.

Comment: I add this rule in my iptables "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j LOG" but when I ping my host to entry added to /var/log/messages

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: what's the question?  I don't understand your last comment.  If you're using the syntax `-A INPUT`, that appends to the end of the INPUT table, so any rule that already accepts or rejects the packet would catch it.